# Using Environment.UserName on a StreamReader

Tags: vb.net, streamreader

I need help in changing the `\bob\` part to something like `\%username%\` when locating the file to read.

I've been reading and everything is saying `Environment.UserName` but how do I add this to my current code?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim sr As New StreamReader("C:\Users\bob\Dropbox\Apps\Attachments\my.txt")
        Dim word As String = ""
        Dim words(1000) As String
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        Do Until sr.Peek = -1
            word = sr.ReadLine()
            words(i) = word

            mytext.AppendText(vbNewLine + vbNewLine + TimeOfDay + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + words(i) + vbNewLine + "__________________________________________")
            i += 1

        Loop

        sr.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
Dim sr As New StreamReader
    ("C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + "\Dropbox\Apps\Attachments\my.txt")
```

Comment: @ENCORECo Cool :)

Answer (score 0):

Adding on from [Bali C's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43096212/6375113) I would also implement [Using](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) which will help with the disposing of the `StreamReader` and it would be good practice to use [Path.Combine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd784047(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Using sr As New StreamReader(Path.Combine("C:\Users", Environment.UserName, "Dropbox\Apps\Attachments\my.txt"))

    'Do your work

End Using
```